# How to add classes to BODY tag dynamically based on page path/depth?

Tags: 7, theming

How to add classes to the body tag dynamically such as this example below?

-Home

-Cities      

--Melbourne       `<body class="melbourne">`

---Theme Parks       `<body class="melbourne theme_parks">`

---Restaurants       `<body class="melbourne restaurants">`

--New York       `<body class="new_york">`

---Theme Parks       `<body class="new_york theme_parks">`

---Restaurants       `<body class="new_york restaurants">`

-Contact Us       `<body class="contact_us">`

Drupal newbie here and without programming background. Therefore, I'd much appreciate if you could be as detailed as possible when sharing a solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To expound on Nikhil Mohan's answer, you can implement [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) inside your theme's template.php file. Read the documentation on [Overriding Themable Output](http://drupal.org/node/173880) to understand the basics of what is going on here.

Within this function, you have access to the variable `$vars['classes_array']`, which holds a list of classes that will be applied to the HTML `<body>` tag on the page.

Unfortunately, information about the current page's location in the menu is not immediately available. You could use [`menu_get_item()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) and then [`menu_get_ancestors()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_ancestors/7) to get this information, but that is a lot of processing power for something that we can probably get to with a simpiler approach.

Assuming you are using the pathauto module to automatically create semantic paths for your content pages based on the menu path (i.e., your Melbourne Theme Parks page would have the path 'melbourne/theme_parks') you can use the page's path to create the classes you are looking for:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  $aliases = explode('/', $path);

  foreach($aliases as $alias) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($alias);
  } 
}
```

That's it. Drupal will now look at the path alias of the current page and add a class to the `<body>` tag for each chunk of the path alias.

Comment: If paths don't work, then parsing [menu_get_active_breadcrumb](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_breadcrumb/7) be an option, too.  It is likely in the `static` cache at that point, so almost no overhead.

Comment: Thank you all, especially @sheena_d for the explanation as well as the code! Had to do a bit of search on how to make it work on Omega Theme and managed to get it to work :D
 
This is the line to make it work on Omega Theme:
 
`$vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($alias);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`template_preprocess_html`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), which Preprocess variables for html.tpl.php

See also [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7)

> Default theme implementation to display the basic html structure of a single Drupal page

Answer (score 1):

Here is the module to add classes on body tag based on role or pages.

[Common Body Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/common_body_class)

Answer (score 0):

Created the [Body Classes Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bodyclasses) to assist with this. Feel free to create issues to add more body class integration points.